# Reading a PCM-encoded 16 bit mono wav file using AudioStreamBasicDescription

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, audio, audiotoolbox

I would like to read a PCM-encoded 16 bit mono wav file using the `AudioStreamBasicDescription` class and I'm currently using the following code to create the format:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription format;
format.mSampleRate = 44100;
format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
format.mFormatFlags = (kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger);
format.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
format.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
format.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
format.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
```

Then I use the `ExtAudioFileSetProperty` method on the `ExtAudioFileRef` object:

```
err = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(eaf, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(format), &format);
if(noErr != err)
{
    // handle error
    NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:err userInfo:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

The error printed is the following:

```
2015-05-20 19:26:12.773 MusicSense[33442:7245119] Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)"
```

I believe there is a mistake in my `AudioStreamBasicDescriptor` but I'm not sure where. I've tried various other options but I get the same error. Did I make a mistake when defining the audio format or could there be something else?